# update atribute in a list of objects using another list using Lambda C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I would like to update an attribute in a list of objects. That attribute comes from a list of aspnetUsers

This is the object

```
Object
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string profesionalId{ get; set; }
   public string attributeToUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

I have this code that is not working

```
List<Object> MyListOfObject=new List<Object>();
// do some queries to populate the list
// more things here...
//my first problem comes here, can not get the list of users
var listOfUsers=  _dbContext.Users.Where(u => MyListOfObject.Any(id => id.ProfesionalId == u.Id)).ToList();
```

If above code is working,  I would like to do a

```
MyListOfObject.ForEach(
 //here replace the MyListOfObject.attributeToUpdate 
).where (MyListOfObject.profesionalId==listOfUsers.Id)
```

Can I get a solution for this please?
I tried my best doing this but could not solve it .Thanks

Comment: Operations like Where and Select are designed specifically to _not_ modify the original collection. However, as you are using a List, you can use `List<T>.ForEach(T => /*do something with T*/)`

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, yes... my problem is that I can not modify the attribute inside the foreach

Comment: Ah, I didn't see you were already using it. You would do `MyListOfObject.ForEach(o => o.attributeToUpdate = newValue)`, but if newValue cannot be calculated once, or needs some sort of indexer, don't feel bad about needing to use a traditional `for` loop.

Comment: the problem is that the new value comes from a list of aspnet users and the problem is how to update where the user.id = mylistOfObject.profesionalId

Comment: If you can't find the answer with LINQ, honestly don't feel defeated if you use a `for` loop with an `if` inside :)

Comment: thank you , I just wanted to be more efficient. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to build the list:

```
var listOfUsers= _dbContext.Users.Where(u => MyListOfObject.Select(c=>c.ProfesionalId).ToList().Contains(u.id)).ToList();
```

but in general you should be able to do like this:

```
MyListOfObject.ForEach(l => l.PropertyToUpdate= _dbContext.Users.First(x => x.id == l.ProfessionalId).PropertyYouGetDataFrom);
```

Comment: thank you very much. This was really useful. Can we use await _dbContext?

Comment: @evvk, I believe enumerations run synchronously